# Typesafe Activator, Play and Heroku

Tags: heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0, typesafe-activator

The steps I do to get the following issue is:

- Start activator
- Create a new project from hello-play sample without changing anything
- git init
- git add .
- git commit -m "init"
- heroku create
- git push heroku master

  ```
         [warn] Multiple resolvers having different access mechanism configured wi
  th same name 'typesafe-ivy-releases'. To avoid conflict, Remove duplicate projec
  t resolvers (`resolvers`) or rename publishing resolver (`publishTo`).
         /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/activator-sbt-atmos-play-shim.sbt:1: error
  : not found: value atmosPlaySettings
         atmosPlaySettings
         ^
         [error] Type error in expression
         Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?  !     Fail
  ed to build app with sbt

   !     Push rejected, failed to compile Play 2.x app
  ```

So I created a brand new project and it's compiling fine locally but not when pushing to Heroku.
What can I do to resolve this issue?
Is Heroku compatible with an activator play project?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Whoops.  We need to have the shim files in the `.gitignore` by default.  I'll fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `activator-sbt-atmos-play-shim.sbt` file from your git repo, add it to the `.gitignore` and then re-push the app.